# Creating my own connector - Access Flow Variables within a MessageDispatcher

Tags: mule

I want my connector to be robust and accept MEL expressions. Right now though I'm having a problem where I'm doing the MEL Evaluator, but what's in my event is not evaluated. I have `<set-variable variableName="key" value="#[payload]" />` and then I do this: `<my-connector:outbound location="#[key] />`.

When I debug this while stepping through my connector, I look into the `MuleEvent` and I see under the `flowVariables` field that `key=#[key]` instead of `key=MyProperty`.

I looked at `LoggerMessageProcessor` to ensure that I'm doing this correctly and my code for evaluation looks the same, but when I debug into the logger, I see that `MuleEvent` has the expression parsed in the `flowVariables`, instead of the notation I showed above.

Is there a trick to having the `MuleEvent` have the expressions of flowVariables already evaluated?

Comment: How could `key=MyProperty` with the example you give? There's no `MyProperty` anywhere.

Comment: In the `set-variable`. Let's say my `#[payload]` was the string `MyProperty`.

Comment: What Mule version are you using?

Comment: Mule 3.3.2. I've already opened a ticket with you on Github to follow this error.

Comment: Really? Which one? Here the issue seems very bad, ie `set-variable` doesn't seem to work for you.

Comment: It's working, but it's not being read by your dispatcher for some reason doesn't get a `MuleEvent` that provides the variable to it. The issue is https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-transport-amqp/issues/24

Comment: Ah OK, sorry, I thought this was about a connector you were creating.

Comment: Tried to make it sound as generic as possible :D